# Physical meaning of the Casimir operators of Poincarè algebra

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, lie-algebra, poincare-symmetry, invariants

If one considers the algebra $su(2)$, it is well known that the [Casimir Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element) is 
$$
    C=L_1^2+L_2^2+L_3^2.
$$
It corresponds to the total angular momentum and correctly is a conserved quantity.

I would like to know which is the physical meaning of the two Casimir operators of the [Poincarè algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group).

Comment: What did you find on Wikipedia and did not understand?

Comment: On Wikipedia you can read "The Casimir invariants of this algebra are $P_\mu P^\mu$ and $W_\mu W^\mu$ where $W_\mu$ is the Pauli–Lubanski pseudovector; they serve as labels for the representations of the group." I've read the definition and their mathematical expression, but I've not understood the physical meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two Casimir operators are $P^2 =P^\mu P_\mu$ where $P$ is momentum, and $W^2 =W^\mu W_\mu$ where $W$ is the so-called Pauli-Lubanski pseudovector.

Evaluating $P^2$ in a particle's rest frame, we find that $P^2 = m^2$, so the first Casimir labels representations by mass.

The Pauli-Lubanski pseudovector is a bit more complicated but also has a simple interpretation in terms of spin. By definition, it's $W^\mu = -\frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} P_\nu S_{\rho\sigma}$, where $S$ is the relativistic spin angular momentum. So $W^2$ has to do with spin. In particular it gives you the particle's spin for massive particles: $ W^2 = -m^2 s(s+1)$ and helicity for massless particles, $ W^2=0$ and $ W^\mu = \pm s P^\mu$.